# How do I wrap EventTarget.addEventListener() so it can be used as an async iterator?

Tags: javascript

How does one use async iterators to consume events coming from a callback, like `EventTarget.addEventListener` and similar?

As an example, the following code does not exist but illustrates what I'd like to see:

```js
for await (const event of onevent('scroll')) {
  console.log(event)
  break // cleanup
}
```

When attempting to create this `onevent` wrapper function, I run into basic issues - like `yield` not being available in the callback (makes sense) and no obvious way to remove listeners when the consumer `break`s their loop.

```js
async function *onevent(eventName) {
  const changeEvent = (event) => {
    yield event // yield cannot be used in this scope
  }

   window.addEventListener(eventName, changeEvent)

   // There doesn't seem to be a way to cleanup on loop "break"
   // window.removeEventListener(eventName, changeEvent)
}

for await (const event of onevent('scroll')) {
  console.log(event)
  break // cleanup?
}
```

Or am I misunderstanding the purpose of async iterators?

Comment: the answer is no `yield` can only be used in `*function`

Comment: https://es.discourse.group/t/event-async-await/1618/5

Comment: @Bergi, weird it's been proposed there, EventTarget is part of DOM, (and we already have that issue open: https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/1038)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how memory efficient it is to create new Promise each time when an event occurs. But this solution works fine.

```js
// async yeild generator function
async function *onevent(eventName) {
  let [hostPromise, hostResolver] = _createResolver();

  window.addEventListener(eventName, function(event) {
    hostResolver(event);
    [hostPromise, hostResolver] = _createResolver();
  })

  while (true) {
    yield await hostPromise;
  }

  function _createResolver() {
    let _resolver;
    _promise = new Promise(res => {
      _resolver = res;
    });
    return [_promise, _resolver];
  }
}

for await (const event of onevent('click')) {
  console.log(event)
}
```

Yes, there's no way to cleanup on "break", you can implement it by returning cleanup function and calling it manualy.

Comment: This is the right way with the promises. There is nothing wrong with creating a promise per event. I have noticed that only very little people know exposing the resolver pattern. In the other answer he adds a new event handler per event which defeats the whole idea of adding one per listener and using it multiple times per event. Also one can use an [asynchronous queue that can be dequeued as an async iterator](https://github.com/kedicesur/AQ) which I had implemented a few years back using the same pattern in it's roots. Very simple and fits like a glove.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have your generator await a new "once" event in a `while` loop.
This way, you can either yield an object with a `clean` property or method, or make your `onevent` function accept an `AbortSignal`, and break the loop based on that.

Quick example with an `AbortController`:

```js
(async() => {
  const controller = new AbortController;
  for await (const event of onevent('click', controller.signal)) {
    if (event.target.closest("button")) {
      controller.abort();
      console.log("cleaning");
      break;
    } else {
      console.log("clicked");
    }
  }
})();

async function* onevent(name, signal) {
  while (!signal.aborted) {
    yield await waitForEvent(window, name);
  }
}

function waitForEvent(target, name) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    target.addEventListener(name, (evt) => {
      res(evt);
    }, {
      once: true
    })
  });
}
```

```html
click anywhere to log
<button>click here to clean</button>
```

And with yielding an object with a `clean()` method:

```js
(async() => {
  for await (const { clean, event } of onevent('click')) {
    if (event.target.closest("button")) {
      clean();
      console.log("cleaning");
      break;
    } else {
      console.log("clicked");
    }
  }
})();

async function* onevent(name, signal) {
  let stopped = false;
  while (!stopped) {
    yield {
      clean() { stopped = true; },
      event: await waitForEvent(window, name)
    };
  }
}

function waitForEvent(target, name) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    target.addEventListener(name, (evt) => {
      res(evt);
    }, {
      once: true
    })
  });
}
```

```html
click anywhere to log
<button>click here to clean</button>
```