# How to use a promise-based (non-event-emitter) approach to streaming data?

Tags: javascript, promise, generator

I want to basically do this when I call a function in my app (frontend):

1. Upload a file. Update progress percent in UI.
2. Create job and return "Job started" in UI.
3. Poll job and wait for it to finish.
4. Return response (converted file in this case).

The UI will basically go through this sequence:

1. Uploading... (with percentage circle updating)
2. Queued...
3. Processing...
4. Complete

All from calling one function.

The function will use `XMLHttpRequest` upload progress functionality, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990090/169992). It will then poll on the backend using `fetch` to get the job status. Finally when the job returns "complete", it will fetch and return the converted file.

What is a proper way of doing that with a promise-based (non event-emitter) approach? Generators?

```
async function *performUploadJob() {
  const workId = yield await upload(getFile())
  yield { type: 'processing' }
  const output = await pollForJobComplete(workId)
  yield { type: 'result', output }
}

async function pollForJobComplete(workId) {
  while (true) {
    const res = await fetch(`/work/${workId}`)
    const json = await res.json()
    if (json.status === 'complete') {
      return json.output
    }
    await wait(2000)
  }
}

function *upload(file) {
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("file", file);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/upload", true);
  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    var percentComplete = Math.ceil((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
    yield { type: 'update', percentComplete }
  };

  xhr.onload = function() {
    if(this.status == 200) {
      yield { type: 'update', percentComplete: 100 }
    }
  }

  xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Is something like that possible (pseudocode)?

If so, how would you structure it? If not, what would you do instead?

The goal is to be able to just do something like this:

```
const iterator = performUploadJob()

for (const data of iterator) {
  switch (data.type) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You have the basic idea, but you need to delegate to other iterables by using the [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) operator and you'll need [`AsyncGenerator`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncGenerator).

Comment: @jsejcksn I am wondering how to handle yielding from `xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e)` currently, that is the hardest part.

Comment: In that case, you might consider closing this question (it's not currently on-topic for SO), and opening a new one that's about creating an async iterator from [`XMLHttpRequest` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#events)

Comment: You might be interested in using an [observable](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) for this kind of scenario.

Comment: @jsejcksn I tried observable, but it was a bit too complex, I think I'm gonna go with Bergi's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [this is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75729946/1048572), but [I wouldn't recommend it](https://es.discourse.group/t/event-async-await/1618/5) because [async iterators are a bad fit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48512319/1048572) for event emitters. Even if you did use `AsyncIterator<ProgressEvent, Response, void>`, it would be rather uneconomic to use, since with a `for await … of` loop you don't get the `Response` result.

- for `pollJob`, an async iterator would be ok, since a) you don't care abou the result (it just stops when done) and b) with polling, you never go faster than the consumer. You can implement this with an async generator similar to what you did:

  ```
  async function* pollForJob(workId) {
    while (true) {
      const res = await fetch(`/work/${workId}`)
      if (!res.ok) throw new Error('Failed to poll'); // or ignore and carry on
      yield res.json()
      await wait(2000)
    }
  }

  …
  for await (const of pollForJob(upload.jobId)) {
    if (json.status === 'complete') {
      break;
    } else if (json.status === 'running') {
      console.log('job continues for', json.estimatedFinish - Date.now());
    }
  }
  console.log('job has finished');
  …
  ```

  If the final poll actually returns the result of the processing, the picture would look different.
- for `upload`, I would recommend to implement a miniature "event loop" where each progress event calls a provided event handler. The event loop terminates when the upload ends, and the promise with the response is resolved (or when there's an error, or if the upload is aborted).

  ```
  function upload(file, onProgress, abortSignal) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      abortSignal?.throwIfAborted();
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append("file", file);

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "/upload", true);

      const stop = done => value => {
        abortSignal?.removeEventListener("abort", fail);
        if (xhr.readyState != 4) xhr.abort();
        reject(err);
      }
      const fail = stop(reject);
      abortSignals?.addEventListener("abort", fail);

      xhr.ontimeout = fail;
      xhr.onerror = fail;
      xhr.onload = stop(e => resolve(e.target));

      xhr.onprogress = e => {
        try {
          onProgress(e);
        } catch(err) {
          fail(err);
        }
      };

      xhr.send(fd);
    });
  }

  …
  const { status, response } = await upload(file, e => {
    var percentComplete = Math.ceil((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
    console.log('completion', percentComplete);
  });
  ```

Comment: Ah I was hoping to avoid the `onProgress`  handler, can you explain more why using the async iterator there is bad-practice? I made the onprogress handler into an async iterator using the EventIterator module, and it seems like it would be fine IMO. But why not? I checked out the links.

Comment: Because `for await (const _ of performUploadJob()) { await sleep(1000); }` will cause problems; and because there is no way to access the response. I don't see what's the problem with passing an `onProgress` handler - it's forced to be synchronous, it will never be called after the `await` has finished, exceptions are handled properly and propagated outside of `upload`.

Comment: Why will it cause problems? It just feels so much cleaner to not have the callback IMO. In the callback way, it does half the stuff one way, and half another...

Comment: Because the events might fire faster than they get processed. And I see nothing wrong with doing it in a different way than the polling, because it *does* different things.

Comment: Ok I see, yeah I can see that, as I show in the bottom of this follow up question based on what you are saying: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/1ar6tvz/why_are_async_generators_bad_in_javascript_this/ I would like to see (a) in more detail what would happen (maybe I'll eventually setup a codesandbox example), and (b) if there are mitigations while still keeping the async generator api (like calling "pause" on the generator?).

Comment: @Lance It *does* pause the iterator (by simply not advancing it further), which is fine if it's a generator but necessarily lead to queuing if the source it keeps producing events. (At least I hope that is what `EventIterator` would do, it might of course be buggy and skip events, or skipping them might be considered a "feature"). But sure, go ahead and try it out (or [read the docs](https://github.com/rolftimmermans/event-iterator#backpressure), they sound like it's done properly).

Comment: Alright I've come around to your side haha. The async iterator on progress events was delayed too much, I tried [`Observable` system](https://github.com/termsurf/task/blob/2ee4ea5215bdcd62e249059e2a3af281b18617da/code/tool/browser/work.ts#L101-L188), but it's overkill and messes with the API too much, so `onUpdate` callback it is!